# How can I analyze and resolve a freezing menu bar?

Tags: macos, performance, menu-bar

My menu bar is freezing up. Whenever I put my cursor near it, I get the spinning wheel of death (rainbow ball). I opened spotlight and it's stuck indexing. The progress bar isn't moving.

I've tried rebooting, I've killed SystemUI and I've removed the SystemUI preference file but the problem persists.

How can I further analyze and resolve this issue?

Comment: Also, apps are hanging too. Here's CleanMyMac2's log. http://pastebin.com/fCmcjUr1

Comment: That's a crash report which may or may not be related to the problem at hand. To get some more details here, can you add a (link to a) screenshot of Activity Monitor (ordered by CPU%) and check whether any of the logs in `/var/log` show anything interesting? It might also help to deactive any add-ons which install themselves in the menu bar and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem for a while now and finally figured out how to fix it. My problem was directly related to 3-party menu icons though, FYI.

Open the utility called Activity Monitor and select the offending applications (they will be red and say "not responding") one at a time. Then click the upper leftmost button with the X in it and select Force Quit. That should remove the icon from the menu bar.